# filling array in for cycle

Tags: java, arrays, cycle

I fill the array and want to check if it was filled right.
If i do like this

```
PositionOnBoard[] pos = new PositionOnBoard[positions.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
            pos[i] = parse(positions[i]);
            System.out.println(pos[i]);
        }
```

My output of array is right, for example [1, 2, 3, 4] but if i do like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
            pos[i] = parse(positions[i]);
            System.out.println(pos[i]);
}
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));
```

The array consists only of last input element [4, 4, 4, 4]. They fill all length of array. What is wrong with this in Java?
P.S Posted all class code

```
public class PositionOnBoard {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    PositionOnBoard(){
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    PositionOnBoard(int a, int b) throws IllegalPositionException {
        if(a > 7 || b > 7){
            throw new IllegalPositionException("Wrong position");
        }
        else{
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }
    }
    private String getCharForNumber(int i) {
        char[] alphabet = "abcdefgh".toCharArray();
        if (i > 8) {
            return null;
        }
        return Character.toString(alphabet[i]);
    }
    private int getNumberForChar(char c) {
        int a = (int) c;
        int b = (int) 'a';
        return a - b;
    }
    public PositionOnBoard parse(String position) throws IllegalPositionException {
        this.x = getNumberForChar(position.charAt(0));
        this.y = position.charAt(1) - '1';
        if(this.x > 7 || this.y > 7){
            throw new IllegalPositionException("Wrong position");
        }
        else return this;
    }
    public String LegalMoveChecker(String[] positions) throws IllegalPositionException {
        PositionOnBoard[] pos = new PositionOnBoard[positions.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
            pos[i] = parse(positions[i]);
            System.out.println(pos[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));
        return "Legal";
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String c = getCharForNumber(x);
        return (c  + String.valueOf(y + 1));
    }

}
```

Comment: There really isn't enough information provided by yu to give a clear answer. If I'd have to guess, however, i'd wager you declared the fields in your `PositionOnBoard` class as `static`. Can you post the `PositionOnBoard` class? Adding the code for the `parse` method would also be very helpful

Comment: What is `positions` ? What does it contains ? What does the `toString()` method of the class `PositionOnBoard` do ?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Posted all code of class

Comment: @vincrichaud I have posted all code of class

Comment: @vincrichaud positions contains positions of horse on chess table. I want to check if horse moves are legal

Comment: @Yan Your method `parse` does modify the object that it is called from and then return that object itself with `return this`. So you constantly modifying one object and adding it again to the array. If you want you parse method to not modify the existing object than you need to create an new PositionOnBoard and then modify and return that new Object.

Comment: A [mre], please? It will help greatly in answering your question.